# Silent install of chrome extension using registry

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For some reason I cannot get this to work. I'm following the exact procedure described here
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry

And I still cannot get the extension listed. If I install it manually, using "Add Unpacked Extension" it works just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I've seen malware using this method to install extensions on current version of chrome as of this week. I did have to run an exe for the extension to get installed though.

Answer (score 4):

[One of many writeups](http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/12/21/google-chrome-25-will-disable-silent-extension-installation-kill-all-such-extensions-retroactively/) on this subject:

> Google on Friday announced that it is changing its stance for silently
>   installing extensions in its browser. As of Chrome 25, external
>   extension deployment options on Windows will be disabled by default
>   and all extensions previously installed using them will be
>   automatically disabled.

You're much better off submitting your extension to the Chrome Web Store. If you really want to install off-store, consider [inline installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation).

Comment: Good answer, but I just want to clarify that when you suggest that inline installation is "off-store", the extension still hosted in Google's Web Store, but the user doesn't need to navigate away from your page.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't mean to confuse readers and do appreciate your clarification. Perhaps a better statement would be "if you're interested in an off-store experience, the closest that the Chrome Web Store has to offer is inline installation, where the sales pitch for the app can be delivered on your own site, and only once the user makes the decision to install does the Chrome installation UI kick in." But yes, the extension remains hosted on CWS, not on your own site.

Comment: This is rather confusing - As per this document - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions -
it is no longer possible to register "local" extensions, but only "published" ones.

"In the Windows registry, the update_URL must point to the Chrome Web Store where the extension is hosted."

This suggests that its still possible to use the registry to install extension - even if only published ones.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with installing an addon via the registry as well. I was successful with installing an addon without adding reg keys. And using the preferences file.

I extracted my extension to `Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\${ADDONID}\${VERSION}`

I then added my extension directly to the `Preferences` file in `Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` under the section `extensions` `settings` `${ADDONID}` <-- add your extension. Compare the Preferences file to an instance you have already installed your addon. And copy that to the Preferences file along with the extension directory on a fresh install. And it should work.

This thread gave me some direction:
https://superuser.com/questions/462804/how-to-copy-an-extension-from-one-chrome-installation-to-another