# How to enable chrome extension without user intervention (programmatically)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window, registry

I made a chrome extension and want its installation to be done as a part of software installation setup using windows registry. It installs the extension for chrome, but in disabled state. Extension is listed in the list of installed extension in chrome://extensions. How can I enable the extension using code(without end-user intervention). I don't want my user to enable it manually.

Comment: you can't because of chrome security police

Comment: could you please share some link and source which says it is not possible because of chrome security policies.

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya, With a little elaboration, what you have in comments would make an answer.

Comment: yaah why not :) @Makyen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent install of chrome extension using registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056498/silent-install-of-chrome-extension-using-registry)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly enable chrome extension because of chrome security police(After Chrome 25).

Extensions installed by third party programs using external extension deployment options will be **disabled** by default. When a third party program installs an extension, the Chrome menu will be badged, and users can click through the Chrome menu to see a dialog containing an option to enable the extension or to remove it from their computer.

In addition, all extensions previously installed using external deployment options will be **automatically disabled**. Chrome will show a one-time prompt to allow the **re-enabling** of any of the extensions.

[image]

But you can use inline installation but you need to upload your extension in Chrome Web Store and ask to user directly like this.

[image]

For More information check below links :

- [No more silent extension installs](https://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html)
- [Protecting Windows users from malicious extensions](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html)