# Chrome Extension / Add a cookie automatically in the background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I would like to develop a chrome extension to automatically add a cookie to a domain.

I want my cookie to be added without user interaction to the extension;

Adding my cookie will be done in the background (here in `persistent.js`).

Is it possible to achieve this?

I tested this:

```
function cookieinfo(){
    chrome.cookies.set({"name":"user","url":"http://mywebsite/","value":"myvalue"},function (cookie){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
        console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
}
window.onload=cookieinfo;
```

But this script does not really work.

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name" : "Cookie Demo",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : "Cookie API",
  "permissions": ["cookies", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "iconon128.png"
  },
  "background": { "scripts": ["persistent.js"], "persistent": true },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I am a beginner and I do not know everything about it ..

Thanks in advence

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(cookieinfo); instead of window onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, adding cookies without user interaction is not possible due to existing [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

You'll need to [declare permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) in your manifest, and as discussed in this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies), `host permissions` should also be declared for any hosts whose cookies you want to access.

Check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514975/how-to-enable-chrome-extension-without-user-intervention-programmatically) for additional insights.

Comment: Thanks you very mutch for your help, i go read this documents :)